# timestampdiff() parameters error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlfiddle

I am using mysql version 5.6 on sql fiddle, and I'm trying to use timestampdiff() function to find the difference between the minimum value in the first column and the largest value in the second one in a table named Task as following

```
select TimeStampDiff(month, , max(Task.End_Date), min(Task.Start_Date));
```

but when I run this code I get the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' months(max(End_Date)), months(min(Start_Date)))' at line 1

is it that timestampdiff() does not accept an aggregate function as a parameter ? and how can I solve this problem?

here's my [complete fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f2dd/4)

Comment: See the syntax: [TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff). You should not have problems with aggregate functions. If you publish your sql-fiddle, we can help you better.

Comment: @wchiquito I've just published it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Task`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Task` (
    ->   `ID` INT NOT  NULL,
    ->   `Pro_ID` INT NOT  NULL,
    ->   `Start_Date` DATE,
    ->   `End_Date` DATE,
    ->   `Description` VARCHAR(255),
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `Task` VALUES
    ->   (1, 1, '2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', "no-Description-yet"),
    ->   (2, 1, '2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', "no-Description-yet"),
    ->   (3, 1, '2017-01-01', '2017-06-01', "no-Description-yet"),
    ->   (4, 2, '2017-01-01', '2017-03-01', "no-Description-yet"),
    ->   (5, 3, '2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', "no-Description-yet"),
    ->   (6, 4, '2017-01-01', '2017-03-01', "no-Description-yet");
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    -> `Pro_ID`,
    -> TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, MIN(`Start_Date`), MAX(`End_Date`)) `MONTH_DIFF`
    -> FROM `Task`
    -> GROUP BY `Pro_ID`;
+--------+------------+
| Pro_ID | MONTH_DIFF |
+--------+------------+
|      1 |          5 |
|      2 |          2 |
|      3 |          1 |
|      4 |          2 |
+--------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Example [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Lk45eYYJnpS1QcEBakUe1/0).